# Proof that Fourier coefficients are minimizing the expression

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be Hilbert space and let $(e_k)_{k=0}^{n}$ be a sequence of orthonormal vectors. Prove that for any $h\in H$ the expression
$$\|h-\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_k e_k \|$$
$c_k\in \mathbb{C}, k=0,1,\dots,n$

is minimal when $c_k=<h,e_k>$

Comment: Compute $$\left\lVert h - \sum_{k=0}^n c_k e_k\right\rVert^2.$$

Comment: $<h-\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_k e_k , h-\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_k e_k  >$ ?

Comment: Yes, although it may be advantageous to write $$h - \sum_{k=0}^n c_k e_k = h - \sum_{k=0}^n \langle h,e_k\rangle e_k + \sum_{k=0}^n \left(c_k - \langle h,e_k\rangle\right) e_k.$$

Comment: Thanks for hints, I will try it myself and hopefully post answer in a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember from calculus where you were give a point $p$ and you wanted to find the closest point on a line or a plane to $p$? You found the orthogonal projection of $p$ onto that line or plane. See if you can't prove a similar thing for $H$:

> **Theorem**: Let $H$ be an inner-product space, and let $M$ be a subspace of $H$. Let $x \in H$ be given. Consider $d(m)=\|x-m\|$ for $m \in M$. The function $d(m)$ has a minimum at $m_{0}\in M$ iff $(x-m_{0},m)=0$ for all $m \in M$.

This theorem is related to the pythagorean theorem $\|x+y\|^{2}=\|x\|^{2}+\|y\|^{2}$ if $(x,y)=0$.

Comment: $\|x-m\|^2 =\|x-m_0+m_0-m\|^2 = \|m_0-m\|^2 + \|x-m_0 \|^2 \ge \|x-m_0\|^2$

Comment: That's it. And the other half: if $x-m_{0}$ is not orthogonal to some unit vector $\hat{m}\in M$, then $\|x-m_{0}-(x-m_{0},\hat{m})\hat{m}\|^{2}=\|x-m_{0}\|^{2}-|(x-m_{0},\hat{m})|^{2}$ is smaller than $\|x-m_{0}\|^{2}$.

Comment: Could you explain the first equality?

Comment: If $a=x-m_{0}$ and $b=(x-m_{0},\hat{m})\hat{m}$, then $(a,b)=(b,a)=|(x-x_{0},\hat{m})|^{2}$ and $\|b\|^{2}=|(x-m_{0},\hat{m})^{2}$ so that $\|a-b\|^{2}=\|a\|^{2}-2(\cdots)+(\cdots)$. (Notice that $(x-m_{0},\hat{m})\hat{m}$ is the projection of $x-m_{0}$ onto the line $\mathcal{l}$ through the origin with direction vector $\hat{m}$. So draw a calculus picture to see why this reduces the distance.)